# eclipse pydev refuses to parse a .py file

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm having a problem with eclipse+pydev. It suddenly refuses to parse a .py file as a python script, which means no syntax highlighting, code completion etc. It worked up until now, but I couldn't find a way to convince it to re parse it. re-opening the file, re-starting the IDE does not help. I suspect deleting some kind of meta-data file would do the trick.

Has anyone here encountered this and has a quick solution? I would greatly appreciate that!

Comment: Have you checked python library files path?

Comment: Could there be a syntax error in the Python script?

Comment: did you try to right click the file and see what the default editor is by selecting "open with"? Maybe it somehow went back to plain text editor, when it should be pydev

Comment: @JamesR -yup, that was the probem, thanks! you should post this as an answer for future generations, and also so I could accept it.

Comment: @WeaselFox cool, thanks. Just posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the python file you care about and see what the default editor is. You can manually switch any file type here. If it's plain text, just switch it back to PyDev.

To ensure that the setting is global, go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File associations and look for .py, .pyw, and .pyx. They should all be set to "Python Editor (default)". If not, just select it and select default. If it's not there at all, you can select the "add" button and add it from there.